# java airplane seating chart array

Tags: java, arrays

i have an issue with my 2d array its not outputting correctly, so the program is running fine, however when i choose case 4 to view airplane seating chart horizontally outputting to many x's and not in the correct spot. if any one can point me in the right direction that will be awesome!

```
public static void viewSeatingChartVertical(boolean seat[]){
  for(int  i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
     for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
        if(seat[((j + 1) + (i * 3)) - 1])
           System.out.print("x ");
        else
           System.out.print("o ");
        }
        System.out.println();
     } 
}

public static void viewSeatingChartHorizontal(boolean seat[]){
              int [][] twoDim = new int [3][10];

              int a = (twoDim.length);
              int b = (twoDim[0].length);   

              for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){ 
              for(int j = 0; j < b; j++) { 
              int x = 0; 
              twoDim[i][j] = x;

           if(seat[((j + 1) + (i * 3)) - 1])
           System.out.print("x ");
           else
           System.out.print("o ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
       }   


 public static void main(String args[]){

  java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);// if the system doesnt know the Scanner function it then looks to import it

  boolean seating[] = new boolean[30];//declare the amount of seats available on the plane in an array

  //display list of options - saving space make easier to read on smaller screen    
System.out.println("Please choose an option:");
System.out.println("1 for “first class”");
System.out.println("2 for “economy”");
System.out.println("3 to view seating chart");
System.out.println("4 to view seating horizontally chart");
System.out.println("0 to exit");
System.out.print("? ");

  while(true){                                                                                          //loop while valid
     int mOpt = input.nextInt();                                                        //mOpt Menu Option - validate number entered, must be 0-4
        switch (mOpt){
        case 0: System.exit(0);
          break;                                                                                        //system exit

        case 1:                                                                                         // first class seats
        {
        System.out.print("Which seat would you like (1-9)\n");
        int fcseat = input.nextInt();
           if(fcseat > 0 && fcseat <10){
              if(seating[fcseat - 1]){
              System.out.print("That seat is taken.\n");
              }
              else{
              seating[fcseat - 1] = true;
              System.out.print("Seat number " + fcseat + " was assigned.\n");
              }
           }
        }
        break;

        case 2:                                                                                         // economic seats 
        {
        System.out.print("Which seat would you like (10-30)\n");
        int econSeat = input.nextInt();
           if(econSeat >= 10 && econSeat <= 30){                                                                    // HAD 31 NOT 30. SMH
              if(seating[econSeat - 1]){
              System.out.print("That seat is taken.\n");
              }
              else{
              seating[econSeat - 1] = true;
              System.out.print("Seat number " + econSeat + " was assigned.\n");
              }
            }
        }
        break;

        case 3:                                                                                         //printout of available seats vertically
        {
        viewSeatingChartVertical(seating);
        }
        break;

        case 4:                                                                                         //printout of available seats horizontally
        {
        viewSeatingChartHorizontal(seating);
        }
        break;

        default:                                                                                        //wrong format or number please try again
        System.out.print("Sorry, Option not recognized, please Try again.\n");
   }      
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up rows and columns on the plane with rows and columns on the screen.

Your horizontal output is really over complicated.  It should be just as simple as the vertical output.  The key is duplicate the code from your vertical output, but reverse the two `for` statements.

```
for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
```

and it should magically work.

Well, almost work.  This will flip the left and right sides of the plane.  A small change to the first loop will fix that too.  Left to student.